# How to call results of a Boolean method in a main method

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, methods, boolean

So, school has moved us on to Java, without really explaining the basics.

Right now I have an issue where I have a class with a  method equalsTest that tests whether two names are the same. Then in my main method I have to call the results of equalsTest and print "Same friend" if the names are the same (equalsTest = true) and "not same friend" if the names are different (equalsTest = false)

```
public class Person {

/* Attribute declarations */
private String lastName;    // last name
private String firstName;   // first name
private String email;       // email address

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;       
    this.email = email;
}

//there are a few other methods in here but are not necessary for the issue explained

public boolean equalsTest(Person other){
    if (this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)&& this.lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    // create a friend
    Person friend1 = new Person("Mickey", "Mouse", "");
    friend1.setEmail("mickey@uwo.ca");

    // create another friend
    Person friend3 = new Person ("Mickey", "Mouse", "");

    // create a friend without email
    Person friend2 = new Person("Minnie", "Mouse", "");

//Here I need another method that calls the "true" or "false" boolean result of the equalsTest method above and says "if equalsTest true, print "Same Friend", and if equalsTest false, print "Not Same Friend", etc.
```

Also, part of the requirement for the lab is that I CANT edit the equalsTest method, I have to call it in the main method. I know it would be easier to just make a section in the main method that would analyze it, but can't do it.

Comment: What are you looking for? `friend2.equalsTest(friend3)`?

Comment: As explained, I have a method that returns true or false if friend1 equals friend2, what I need is a piece of code in a different method, to call the results of the first method, and if the result is true, print out "same friend" and if the results are false, print out "not same friend"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to call the function and do something on a true return or a false return of the method call. You can use a simple if/else. You can also use the [Ternary Operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) which is very useful for when you only have two outcomes you care about.

(condition) ? (true goes here) : (false goes here)

```
String testResultOutput = "";

testResultOutput = friend1.equalsTest(friend3) ? "Friends are the same" : "Friends are NOT the same";
System.out.println(testResultOutput);

testResultOutput = friend2.equalsTest(friend3) ? "Friends are the same" : "Friends are NOT the same";
System.out.println(testResultOutput);
```

Output based on your main would be

```
Friends are the same
Friends are NOT the same
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, still testing. Before I posted I tried doing
results = friend2.equalsTest(friends1); and then an if statement, if true or if false. Kept getting an error, I didn't know you could include the ? "Friends are the same"... etc. 

Do you have any articles that explain this? First time I've heard of it

Comment: did you click on the link to the Ternary explanation? that explains how the ternary operation works

Answer (score 0):

```
if(friend1.equalsTest(friend2)) {
  System.out.print("Same");
}
else {
  System.out.print("Not same");
}
```

Comment: That looks more like Python, I'm trying this in Java. As well, I already have a method that returns true or false if the names are the same. I cannot change this method to include the print. I have to create another section in a main method that takes the results from the first method and then prints based on those results.

Comment: thats not java.

Comment: I edited the answer to pure java syntax. You call this piece of code from main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can by doing this in your main

```
if(friend1.equalsTest(friend2))
     System.out.println("same");
 else
     System.out.println("not the same);
```

Comment: have you read the question? - "Also, part of the requirement for the lab is that I CANT edit the equalsTest method"

Answer (score 0):

I would add a print method otherwise you always have to call the `equalsTest` method.

```
public void printFriendsEqual(Person a) {
    if (this.equalsTest(b)) {
        System.out.println("Friends are the same");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Friends are NOT the same");
    }
}
```

and than call it in main:

```
// create another friend
Person friend3 = new Person ("Mickey", "Mouse", "");
Person friend2 = new Person("Minnie", "Mouse", "");
friend3.printFriendsEqual(friend2);
```

Answer (score 0):

make you Boolean method to static...
now you can use in Conditional statement if...else

```
public static boolean equalsTest(Person other){..}

private void myMethod(){
  // Person other = new Person ("Mickey", "Mouse", "");
if(equalsTest(Person other)) {...}
}
```